# mysql connection design and concurrent connections

Tags: php, mysql

My application will be hosted in a shared hosting provider with a limit of 25 Mysql concurrent connections. Below is my code for connecting to DB

```
function dbConnect() {
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'user';
$dbPass = 'pass';
$dbName = 'dbase';  
    mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());
   }
```

My application is more on database query. The home page alone has atleast 20 mysq_query in it. The way I code my home page is like below

```
include 'config.php';
dbConnect();
```

query1 ... //to get initial variables

process variables that result in multiple query

query2... // process result

query3...// process result

and so on up to....

query 20...// process result

I cant minimize the query anymore coz most of the query is prerequisite of the other query. I am expecting of at least 1000 users daily, and the possibility of 50% of the users will connect on the same time or at lest seconds apart.

1. On the design of connecting to DB will I easily reach the connection limit set?
2. Is php closing the connection right after the query, meaning it closes after the first query, then open on the second and closes again right after, and so on and son, even if I'm not closing the connection myself
3. Is my assumption correct that the above scenario automatically consumed 20 concurrent connections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (that is, if it's offered on your server). Don't use `mysql_` functions (`mysqli_` family being marginally better than those).

Comment: And 20 queries (at least) for every request through your system, you need to cache the requestors (users) cacheable database-stored data in the session for the request if possible, not requery for every separate request. Hopefully your data schema isn't designed so you can't do that.

Comment: And you're hopefully able to take advantage of [connection pooling](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php).

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm a newbie in database design, and yes most of the result was put on SESSION if needed, but still I'll be needing that more connection to populate the SESSION.

Comment: Take a look at my link and [`mysql_pconnect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php). If you truly will have 500 concurrent users, maybe 100-150 concurrent requests, with all that action on the server to satisfy a request, and the server is a shared host? Mmm. Mmm.

Comment: My thought is the same. With that volume of concurrent users, you will exceed the connection limit unless you hamper their performance or can do some whizz-bang caching. I'd upgrade your hosting plan, will saved you a lot of problems and make the end user experience better. Otherwise you won't have that many users for long

Comment: @Robbie, is that mean my connection design to DB is okay?

Comment: No, you at least need to look into `mysql_pconnect()` and share a connection across requests. you essentially open it and then leave it open. This is called [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

Comment: To quote from the above link: *Opening and maintaining a database connection for each user, especially requests made to a dynamic database-driven website application, is costly and wastes resources.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, some answers to questions 2. and 3. of genpet's original post:

1. PHP closes your connection to MySQL if and only if (assuming it wasn't openned with `mysql_pconnect()`):

   - you call `mysql_close()`
   - you reach the end of the script
2. Therefore, if you send 20 queries during the same script, you only consume 1 connection

One thought just comes to my mind. Consider this pattern:

- open/poll a connection with `*_pconnect()`
- run a query, deal with the results
- release the connection ASAP with `*_close()`
- open/poll again if you need to query the DB later in the script

This way, I believe one could work around the low concurrent connections limit (even though I agree with people advising your hosting plan may be inappropriate to fulfill your needs)

This is theory, though, I haven't tried that in the real.

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me post this as an comment above, so this isn't an answer, but an extension of my first comment ("upgrade your hosting plan")

IMO, your connection design is not ok. "die" is a terminal function, if you're expecting failure, then build in a retry option and a user friendly error handling function. Also, opening and closing the DB each time is time intensive, you might be able to squeeze three queries faster than closing down and opening again for one (but that depends on several factors, which can be mitigated worth shared pools add suggested by others.) But my advice is upgrade hosting plan and develop "normally". Then your style is ok, except use a friendlier error screen than "die" :-) as well as pdo or mysqli, not mysql_ functions

Comment: I foresee tears of anguish and gnashing of teeth. And that's just the other folks on that shared server. Have 386, will travel? Maybe trouble won't be ahead, but I'd like to know how.

Comment: @Robbie Thanks. 'die' is used only on development stage for me to easily debug. Thanks again.